# how to fetch posts in laravel using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I managed to successfully add ajax into laravel, the following code adds a post via ajax, without page refresh, adds it to the database, however im a bit clueless on how to fetch the posts that i submitted via ajax.

Any Suggestions, no error shows up, i just cant fetch the post via ajax

**app.js**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});



  $('#add').click(function(){            
    $.ajax({
      url: 'createpost',
      type: "post",
      data: {'body':$('textarea[name=body]').val(), '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
      success: function(data){
        $('#new-post').val('');

      }
    });      
  });
```

**PostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function getDashboard()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        $cookie = cookie('saw-dashboard', true, 15);
        $users = User::all();
        $user = new User();
//        return view('dashboard', array('user'=> Auth::user()), compact('users'))->withCookie($cookie);

        return view('dashboard',array('user'=> Auth::user(), 'posts' => $posts,  compact('users')))->withCookie($cookie);

    }



  public function postCreatePost(Request $request) {
      $rules = array(
           'body' => 'required|max:1000'
      );

      $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

      if ($validator->fails()) {
         return Response::json (array(
                 'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray ()
         ));
      } else {
         $post = new Post();
         $post->body = $request->body;
         $request->user()->posts()->save($post);
         return response ()->json( $post );
      }
  }


}
```

**Dashboard.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('title')
Dashboard
@endsection
@section('content')
<div class="dashboard eli-main">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-12">
                <h1>{{$user->username}}</h1>

                <h4>What do you have to say?</h4>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="new-post" rows="5" placeholder="Your Post"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="add" class="mybtn2">Create Post</button>
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
                </form>
                {{ csrf_field() }}



                @foreach($posts as $post)
                        <article class="post">
                         <h4>{{$post->user->username}}</h4>
                            <p class="post-bod">
                                {{ $post->body }}
                            </p>
                            <div class="info">
                               made on {{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}
                            </div>
                   </article>


                @endforeach


            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

and here is the route

```
Route::post('/createpost',[

    'uses' => 'PostController@postCreatePost',
    'middleware' => 'auth'

]);
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve all posts via ajax?

Comment: @linktoahref, whats up man, you helped me out quite a bit earlier, well all but, im sure i can put a limit to it.

Comment: Onsuccess append retrieved data into your div.

Comment: @Bugfixer can you show an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**postcontroller.php**

Get the posts once you saved them and return it back to the ajax

```
$post = new Post();
$post->body = $request->body; $request->user()->posts()->save($post);

//Retrieve Posts
$responsePosts = Post::all(); // or limit here how many posts you would like to send back

return response ()->json( $responsePosts );
```

**app.js**

The posts data will be available in

```
success: function (data) {
  var posts = JSON.parse(data);
  var temp = '';
  $.each(posts, function(prop, value) {
     temp += "<h4>"+posts['username']+"</h4>"+
             "<p class='post-body'>"+posts['body']+"</p>"+
             "<div class='info'>made on"+posts['created_at']+"</div>";
  });
  $("article.post").html(temp);
```

And you could populate the posts back by appending to

```
<article class="post"></article>
```

Comment: i get Object, Object, Object, its pointing to the console.log(data)

Comment: parse the response using `var posts = JSON.parse(data);` Loop through each posts, to get each post information.

Comment: success: function(data){
        var posts = JSON.parse(data);  
        $('#new-post').val('');

          console.log(posts);

      } doesn't work, : Unexpected token o in JSON at position

Comment: i think im figuring it out, here is what i got so far

      `$(".post").append(JSON.parse(data));` doesn't work, but this does,  `$(".post").append(JSON.stringify(data));`  but i dont want the data formatted like that

Comment: @OwlMan please check the updated code, sorry for the late response though. I think this should get the work done

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the post related data or view using jquery ajax() in laravel very easily like:

Jquery ajax():

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url('/fetchposts')',
    type: "get",
    data: {
        key: value  // pass the data here if you have any like:
        //postId: postId,
        //name: name
    },
    success: function(data){

});
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('/fetchposts',[
    'uses'=>'YourController@fetchPosts'
]);
```

YourController.php:

```
public function fetchPosts()
{
    // From this function either return the entire view with corresponding data into it
      $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    // Or return the JSON array and make the view in success of ajax and appedn it to your html
      return response ()->json( $posts );
}
```

Comment: what do i pass in the key section ?

Comment: i just checked it, is their way i can output the posts in the same format as i have in my dashboard.php, if so how would i go about doing that, thanks mayank.